# finding unique record using min and max in same query from several criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a common table expression with the following fields

```
product.identifier, ingredient.identifier, ingredient.cost,
ingredient.isActive, ingredient.isPrimary
```

I'm trying to find a record based off the following criteria among multiple records

1. if `isActive = 1` and `isPrimary = 1`, choose that record
2. if the record with `isPrimary = 1` but `isActive = 0`, choose the record with the highest/max cost where `isPrimary = 0` and `isActive = 1`
3. if all records from step 2 have the same cost, choose the oldest/min record based off `ingredient.Identifier`

the logic to find these on their own is simple but combining the logic into one clause is not working as expected. here is the expected output I'm trying to match along with the incorrect SQL

```
product ingredient cost  isActive isPrimary   isChosenRecord

-- isActive and isPrimary example                            
1       10         1.00  1        1           yes
1       11         1.10  1        0           no
2       20         2.00  1        1           yes
2       22         2.15  1        0           no

-- primary record is inactive, choose max cost record
3       30         3.00  0        1           no
3       31         3.10  1        0           no
3       32         3.20  1        0           yes
4       40         4.00  0        1           no
4       41         4.10  1        0           no
4       42         4.20  1        0           yes

-- primary record is inactive, all records have same cost, choose oldest record
5       50         5.00  0        1           no
5       51         5.00  1        0           yes
5       52         5.00  1        0           no
6       60         6.00  0        1           no
6       61         6.00  1        0           yes
6       62         6.00  1        0           no
```

---

```
; with [ActiveRecordsCTE] as
(
    select
        ProductIdentifier = p.Identifier,
        IngredientIdentifier = i.Identifier,
        i.Cost, i.isActive, i.isPrimary
    from Product p
    inner join Ingredient i on i.Identifier = p.Identifier
    where i.isActive = 1

),

[CalculatedPrimaryRecords] AS 
(
    SELECT
        r.ProductIdentifier,
        r.IngredientIdentifier
    FROM ActiveRecordsCTE r
    WHERE r.IsPrimary = 1

    UNION

    -- get the oldest records
    SELECT
        r.ProductIdentifier,
        IngredientIdentifier = min(r.IngredientIdentifier)
    FROM
    (
        -- get most expensive record by cost
        SELECT
            r.ProductIdentifier,
            r.IngredientIdentifier
        FROM ActiveRecordsCTE a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            -- get most expensive record per product
            SELECT
                r.ProductIdentifier
                ,MaxAssetValue = MAX(r.Cost)
            FROM ActiveRecordsCTE b
            WHERE b.IsPrimary = a.IsPrimary
                AND a.ProductIdentifier = b.ProductIdentifier
                AND a.IngredientIdentifier = b.IngredientIdentifier
            GROUP BY b.ProductIdentifier
        ) ca
        WHERE a.IsPrimary = 0
            -- exclude records that are included in the statement above
            AND a.ProductIdentifier NOT IN
            (
                SELECT ProductIdentifier
                FROM ActiveRecordsCTE
                WHERE IsPrimary = 1
            )
    ) sub
    GROUP BY sub.ProductIdentifier
)

select * from [CalculatedPrimaryRecords]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` for this type of prioritization:

```
with cte as ( . . . )
select t.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product
                                order by (case when isActive = 1 and isPrimary = 1 then 1
                                               when isActive = 0 and isPrimary = 1 then 2
                                               else 3
                                          end),
                                         cost desc, 
                                         identifier asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This makes some assumptions that seem consistent with the question:

- `isActive` and `isPrimary` only take on the values 0 and 1.
- If no records have `isPrimary = 1`, then you still want a record.  (If not, these can easily be filtered out.)
- `identifier` is not defined in your sample data.

EDIT:

If you wanted to be fancy, you could use `top (1) with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties cte.*
from cte
order by row_number() over (partition by product
                            order by (case when isActive = 1 and isPrimary = 1 then 1
                                           when isActive = 0 and isPrimary = 1 then 2
                                           else 3
                                      end),
                                     cost desc, 
                                     identifier asc
                          );
```

I actually prefer the `row_number()` solution because I'm not sure what to do in the case that `isPrimary = 0` and it is easier to add logic for that solution to filter out those records.

Comment: forgot to update question. `identifier` refers to `ingredient.Identifier`

Comment: @IcollectInternetpoints . . . The columns you specify in the text of the question are not consistent with the columns in the CTEs.  You should be able to figure out the right mapping (this answer primarily uses the sample data rather than the code sample).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for the suggestions. as far as the mapping goes, I just need to return those two identifiers based off the criteria (for now) rather than return all the fields considered for prioritization

Comment: @IcollectInternetpoints . . . Just `select` the columns that you need then.